# export to pdf in php javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

i want to download that html output as pdf format.
In that code error was occured only empty tab will be open and it will show a popup message as

failed to load the document

```
  if(comp_id != "Select Company")
                {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'includes/export1.php',
                            data: {action: 'compreport', 'comp':comp_id,   },
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function (output) {
                                $("#pdfreportview").html(output);
                           //     $("#datapdf").val(output);
                            window.open('data:application/pdf,'+ encodeURIComponent( $('div[id$=pdfreportview]').html()));
                            e.preventDefault();
                            },
                            async: false
                            });  
                }
```

Comment: You cannot just export html into PDF... You need some PHP library like tcpdf to create a PDF file.

Comment: You can also try `jsPDF` if you want client side - http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Answer (score 2):

As Salketer mentioned, it's impossible to "export" your document to a PDF this way. In fact, you're not even exporting it.

Converting HTML to PDF requires rendering it, which can be performed by the web browser or dedicated libraries, as suggested in the comments.

What you are doing is giving the user HTML code and telling them at the same time "this is a PDF". Since the two formats vary a lot, the PDF viewer only sees a corrupted PDF and will refuse to show anything.